# Prove that a polynomial is irreducible

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose that $f(x,1)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is irreducible polynomial, with integer coefficient and such that $ \gcd(a,b,c,d)=1$, with some root $ \theta$, i want to prove that $g(x,1)=x^3+bx^2+acx+a^2d$ is irriducibile and it has a root belonging to $ \mathbb{Q}(\theta) $.
If i found a matrix in $\mathbf{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) $ that transform $f(x,y)$ into $g(x,y)$ i'm done, but i can't find any...

Comment: Sorry, typo it is $bx^2$ of course

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

We have
$$a^2 f(x) = a^2 ( a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d ) = (a x)^3 + b (a x)^2 + a c (a x) + a^2 d =  g(a x)$$

Comment: Anyway if  $\theta$ is the root of $f(x,1)$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ is a cubic number field, it is true that $ g(x,1)$ is the minimal polynomial of $a\theta$ ? I think that's true since being $ \theta$ of degree 3 then also $ a \theta $ is of degree $3$ and $g(x,1)$ is monic and it has least degree among those for which $ a \theta $ is a root.

Comment: @3m0o: yes it is true; if you had a polynomial with root $a \theta$ then going backwards you would find a polynomial with root $\theta$.  So there is no poly of smaller degree with root $a \theta$.  (also important is that $g$ is monic, so $a \theta$ is an algebraic integer). Cheers!